# how to create 1 char square

Tags: html, css

Is there some good way to make a square with one character in it, and have that character align in center and v-align in middle.

Like a small green box around the '+' character ( for "good", red around '-' for "bad" or blue around 'i' for "information").

I guess one part of the problem is to use a font thats the same size in most browsers/os.
Another how to pad it so its a square, and the character is centered in it.

Tried setting `width`, `height` and `line-height` to `1 em`, but the '+' ended up a bit off, and with different amount in chromium and firefox, replace '+' with a 'Heavy plus sign' U+2795 made less difference between browsers, but guess it may make worse differences between os.

currently i have

```css
.pros_icon
{
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 height: 1em;
 height: calc(1em + 2px);
 width: 1em;
 width: calc(1em + 2px);
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;

 border: solid black 1px;
 color: white;
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="pros_icon"> ➕ </span>
```

(or maybe I should just use an svg image)

Comment: You can try height or width auto.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the `float:left` and `line-height: 1em;` and use padding

```css
.pros_icon
{
    //float: left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 1em;
    height: calc(1em + 2px);
    width: 1em;
    width: calc(1em + 2px);
    font-size: 20px;
    //line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;

    border: solid black 1px;
    color: white;
    background: green;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="pros_icon"> ➕ </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have revised my answer. This below should be the least amount of code for a fixed height/width. In case you have a non-symmetrical and/or odd shaped symbol with different height/width, you can play around with the line-height to center it vertically

```css
#char-box {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="char-box">O</div>
```

Comment: ends up as 19x29px, not a square

Comment: @PugganSe I have to agree with you. The padding on top/bottom was unnecessary: https://jsfiddle.net/n4gr9tqq/4/ This seems ok. If it is not pitch perfect for your needs we could use a div with vertical align as a wrapper but it will serve the same purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
.good,
.bad,
.info {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: calibri;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.good {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  border: 1px solid darkgreen;
}
.bad {
  background-color: coral;
  border: 1px solid darkred;
}
.info {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid darkblue;
}
```

```html
<span class="good">+</span>
<span class="bad">-</span>
<span class="info">i</span>
```

Comment: best so far (of 4), + a bit high in chrome, and - a bit low in firefox. https://test.puggan.se/test/Screenshot_20160721_145520.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```css
.pros_icon {
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.9;
  border: solid black 1px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 3px;
}
.success {
  background: green;
}
.bad {
  background: red;
}
.info {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="pros_icon success">&plus;</span>
<span class="pros_icon bad">&minus;</span>
<span class="pros_icon info">i</span>
```

This is an alternative way. Try this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BRxKX/7260/)

Comment: testsed the aboce css in your fiddle, looked ok in chrome, but not in firefox:
https://test.puggan.se/test/Screenshot_20160721_144730.png

Comment: the 100x100 was abit too big, hard to see if it was centered